# SqlException: The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint The conflict occurred in database table column

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

i want save record the id_ats and id_ex from another table, but i always get error foreign key constraint. please help me..

Controller :

```
 [HttpPost]                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
    public ActionResult SaveRecord(IEnumerable<exercises> model)
    {
        foreach (var item in model)
        {
            ex_op dbitem = new ex_op();
            if (db.ex_op.Any(x => x.id_test == item.Id))
            {
                dbitem = db.ex_op.Where(x => x.id_test == item.Id).FirstOrDefault();
                dbitem.id_test = item.Id;
                dbitem.id_ats = item.IdAts;
                dbitem.id_ex = item.IdExercises;
                dbitem.start_test = item.StartTest;
                dbitem.end_test = item.EndTest;
                dbitem.best_time = item.BestTime;
                dbitem.performance = item.performance;
                dbitem.status = item.status;
                dbitem.comment = item.comment;
                db.Entry(dbitem).State = EntityState.Modified;
            }
            else
            {
                dbitem.id_test = item.Id;
                dbitem.id_ats = item.IdAts;
                dbitem.id_ex = item.IdExercises;
                dbitem.start_test = item.StartTest;
                dbitem.end_test = item.EndTest;
                dbitem.best_time = item.BestTime;
                dbitem.performance = item.performance;
                dbitem.status = item.status;
                dbitem.comment = item.comment;
                db.ex_op.Add(dbitem);
            }
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
        return RedirectToAction("Index", new { msg = "Sukses" });
    }
```

Comment: Hello, Ayu, and welcome to Stack Overflow. To help address this, we'll likely need more information about your schema and data. I'd also recommend formatting the code so it's easier to read; right now it's really hard to make sense of.

Comment: It's worth noting that a foreign key constraint is intended to ensure data integrity and, if you're violating the constraint, it is fully expected that an error will be thrown. The question you should be evaluating is what field(s) have the foreign key constraint and do the value(s) you're inserting satisfy that constraint?

Comment: hello, Jeremy, thank you for response.I want save the record based on ID in column op_ats and ID in column detail_ex and they're will save to 1 table in table ex_op. so, i create the relationship in the database for get the data ID op_ats and ID detail_ex and then i run the application i getting error like this. but when i delete the relationship table i dont get error but the ID op_ats and ID detail_ex cannot save into table ex_op

Answer (score 0):

Usually with foreign key constraint errors the problem is that the ID you are using to update or insert does not exist in the related table.

E.g. if a box(BoxTable) has apples(AppleTable) and the apple table has a foreign key pointing to box table then a box must exist for an apple to be created or inserted.
If the you use an id that does not exist in the box table then you get a foreign key constraint error.